# Does anyone have experience in developing a LIMS system in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am developing a new Laboratory Management System for my company and I am having trouble with the metals portion of our lab work. Basically how it works is we get a sample in of something, log it in, the lab techs run the analysis, we put the results in, and a report prints out. For example, we could get a paint sample that the customer wants to be tested for Pb, Cd, and Cr.

The way I have it set up now is when you are logging it in, if you select Metals as the module and Paint as the Matrix, a button shows up that when clicked, opens up a subform with all of the elements we test for. You click a checkbox for each element you are testing for, and then when you open the results form, only the elements you selected show up. The problem is that I have 27+ elements that we can test for, each of which needing a field for the result, 3 fields for who analyzed it, 3 fields for the dates it was analyzed, and another field for the reporting limit for that element (it changes depending on a few things) Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than brute forcing hundreds of fields? I am happy to provide the file for my database if anyone would like to take a further look.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to get the design of your database correct to start with, by normalizing it. As a suggestion, try having the following three tables:

**tblTest** - TestID (Primary Key, autonumber), TestName. Other information about the test such as date requested, date completed may be included.

**tblElement** - ElementID (Primary Key, autonumber), ElementName.

**tblTestElement** - TestElementID (Primary Key, autonumber), TestID (Foreign Key from tblTest), ElementID (Foreign Key from tblElement), fields for test date, who analyzed it and so on.

You would then create your main form based on `tblTest`. Create a continuous form based on `tblTestElement` to be used as a subform (linked on TestID), with `tblElement` being used as the RowSource for a combo box on this subform.

Using this structure, you would be able to select as many tests to be conducted as you need, without running into field limitations.

There are two ways that you can allow the user to add common groups at once. Firstly, if there are just one or two, you could use command buttons that insert the data into `tblTestElement` as a set of SQL `INSERT` statements. If there are many, or likely to be additional ones, then look at using a table to store the names of these tests, and another linked table to store the individual tests. Again, you would do an `INSERT` into the table `tblTestElement`.

For printing out a report, again you would use a report/sub-report setup. Base the main report on `tblTest` (and note that when you do `.OpenReport` there is an argument to limit the records returned - `DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTest",acViewPreview,,"TestID=3"`). Create a query joining `tblElement` (to get the name of the element) and `tblTestElement`, and create a sub-report on this query. You then add this sub-report to the main report, joining on `TestID`.

Comment: Oh my god thats the simplest yet best solution, I don't know why I couldn't think of that! need more coffee.. Thank you!

Comment: edit: I've been trying all morning to build it and I just cant seem to wrap my head around your example fully. Each report we do includes a report number (ex: 133505), sample numbers (133505-001, 133505-002, etc), and then each sample number for that batch would need to include element 1 and the associated data, element 2 and the associated data, etc. Is there any way you can help me with an example build? I know its a lot to ask and I completely understand if you don't want to! I swear I am not just being lazy, I just am struggling with conceptualizing this.

Comment: There are also certain groups of elements that are commonly tested together (ex: an RCRA8 test includes the same 8 elements every time)